# Adjusting Luminance of a Color in Stylus

Tags: css, colors, stylus, luminance

I'm working with Stylus, the CSS Pre-processor and I want a function to adjust the "perceived brightness" of the color, say, by 20% or -10%.

I discovered the term "luminance", and it looks like Stylus has a function to **get** the luminance of a color, but not adjust a colors luminance.

How can such a function be created?

Comment: `lighten` function isn't enought for your purposes

Comment: Or much better `lightness` e.g: `lightness(#000, 50%) ==> #808080`

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, this one seems to work. I'm not sure if it's 100% correct though.

```
adjust-luminance($color, $amount = 10%)
    $scale = unit($amount, '') / 100 * 255

    //green is the lightest component, followed by red, then blue.
    $redWeight = 0.2126
    $greenWeight = 0.7152
    $blueWeight = 0.0722

    // get the individual components of the color
    $red = red($color)
    $green = green($color)
    $blue = blue($color)

    //get percent
    $percentRed = $red / 255
    $percentGreen = $green / 255
    $percentBlue = $blue / 255

    $lumRed = $percentRed * $redWeight
    $lumGreen = $percentGreen * $greenWeight
    $lumBlue = $percentBlue * $blueWeight

    $lumTotal = 1 + ($lumRed + $lumGreen + $lumBlue)

    $red += $scale * (1 - $redWeight) * $lumTotal
    $green += $scale * (1 - $greenWeight) * $lumTotal
    $blue += $scale * (1 - $blueWeight) * $lumTotal

    $adjusted = rgb($red, $green, $blue)
    $adjusted = saturation($adjusted, saturation($color))
    return $adjusted
```